# Weird C# compiler issue with variable name ambiguity

Tags: c#

Let's take the following code:

```
class Foo
{
   string bar;

   public void Method()
   {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.bar))
      {
         string bar = "Hello";
         Console.Write(bar);
      }
   }
}
```

This will compile, and all is good.  However, let's now remove the `this.` prefix:

```
class Foo
{
   string bar;

   public void Method()
   {
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar)) // <-- Removed "this."
      {
         string bar = "Hello";
         Console.Write(bar);
      }
   }
}
```

In this case, I get a compiler error.  I agree this is an error, however it's the location of the error that confuses me.  The error happens on the line:

```
string bar = "Hello";
```

With the message:

> A local variable named 'bar' cannot be declared in this scope because
>   it would give a different meaning to 'bar', which is already used in a
>   'parent or current' scope to denote something else

From what I understand about the compiler, the declaration of `bar` gets *hoisted* to the top of the `Method()` method.  However, if that's the case, the line:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar))
```

Should be considered ambiguous, as `bar` could be a reference to the instance field or to the not-yet-declared local variable.

To me, it seems odd that removing `this.` can cause a compilation error on another line.  In other words, declaring a local `bar` variable is perfectly valid, *as long as* no potentially *ambiguous* references to `bar` have been made previously in the scope (note, if I comment out `if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar))` then the error goes away).

**That all seems rather pedantic, so what's your question?:**

My question is why the compiler allows an ambiguous reference to a variable before it's declared in the scope, but then flags the declaration itself as *redundant*.  Shouldn't the ambiguous reference to `bar` in `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` be a more precise location of the error?  In my example, it's of course easy to spot, but when I ran across this issue in the wild, the reference was pages up and much harder to track down.

Comment: looks like it's already declared at the class level and that looks to be a normal compiler error you are re-declaring the string bar = "Hello"; inside of the if CodeBlock.. it's just a simple scope issue

Comment: @DJKRAZE: That doesn't explain why adding a `this.` to the first reference makes the second reference compile!

Comment: Once again the silly 'lexical' scoping of C#...

Comment: Eric Lippert has a blog post on the subject, if you're looking for him to comment ;) [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/02/simple-names-are-not-so-simple.aspx).

Comment: Yea, I don't think this is a scoping question (I understand scoping just fine).  Jon cleared it up through the language spec - Once you use a name, every other occurrence of the same identifier must refer to the same entity.  However, it's basically a "first one wins" approach.  The first time I refer to `bar`, *that's* the entity all future references must refer to.  Thus the new declaration of the local `bar` is a violation.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> From what I understand about the compiler, the declaration of bar gets hoisted to the top of the Method() method.

No, that's not the case.

The error message is quite precise here:

> A local variable named 'bar' cannot be declared in this scope because it would give a different meaning to 'bar', which is already used in a 'parent or current' scope **to denote something else**.

The part of the C# spec which is being violated is section 7.6.2.1 (C# 4 and 5 specs):

> **Invariant meaning in blocks**
>   For each occurrence of a given identifier as a full simple-name (without a type argument list) in an expression or declarator, within the local variable declaration space (§3.3) immediately enclosing that occurrence, every other occurrence of the same identifier as a full simple-name in an expression or declarator must refer to the same entity. This rule ensures that the meaning of a name is always the same within a given block, switch block, for-, foreach- or using-statement, or anonymous function.

And in the annotated C# specification, this has a helpful annotation from Eric Lippert:

> One of the more subtle desirable consequences of this rule is that it becomes safer to undertake refactorings that involve moving around local variable declarations. Any such refactoring that would cause a simple name to change its semantics will be caught by the compiler.

Aside from anything else though, it seems to me that this is just good for clarity. Even if the second version were allowed, the first is clearer IMO. The compiler is ensuring that you don't write pathologically unclear code, when you can very easily fix it to be obvious what you mean where.

To put it another way: do you *really* want to be able to write the second version?

In particular:

> In my example, it's of course easy to spot, but when I ran across this issue in the wild, the reference was pages up and much harder to track down.

... and that makes it *more* reasonable to allow it? Quite the reverse, I'd say - and you should also treat it as strong encouragement to refactor your code so that a single method isn't "pages" long.

Comment: Thanks Jon!  This is actually the exact answer I was hoping for, complete with reference to the appropriate place in the language spec clarifying this behavior.  I've just never before ran into a situation where removing a `this.` prefix resulted in a *new* compiler error *elsewhere in the program*, and wanted to gain insight into the design decisions behind this.

Comment: I actually don't understand why StackOverflow even *allows* you to downvote a Jon Skeet answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second definition of bar is not pulled to the method level, its scope is the if block.  For example this is completely valid.

```
class Foo
{
    private string bar;

    public void Method()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar)) // <-- No more this.
        {
            string bar1 = "Hello";
            Console.Write(bar);
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(bar)) // <-- No more this.
        {
            string bar1 = "Hello";
            Console.Write(bar);
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is that `bar` is no longer ambiguous, there is a clear name distinction between the outer and inner scope of `bar`/`bar1` - the compiler disallows overriding the outer scope `bar` by a local definition.

Comment: doesn't quite answer the question.

Comment: @gdoron, he has several questions in there.  At one point he says that he agrees it is an error but doesn't agree with where the error occurs because he believe the second declaration of bar is pulled to the top of the Method().

Comment: I didn't downvote, well, let's say it answers a part of the question. :)

Comment: @gdoron, agree to disagree, the question has been edited and sums up his question in the last paragraph, I think my answer is right on track.  His confusion is not whether it is an error, but where the error should have been because he didn't understand the scoping of the variables.